# @vue/compiler-sfc cannot compile code in <script setup>

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vite, vue-sfc

I tried to use `@vue/compiler-sfc` to compile `.vue` files, I did succeed, but only if the code is placed in `<script>` tags, when I compile if the code in `<script setup>`, the result will be error. The following is my `compiler.js` file. Executing `node compiler.js` in CMD will compile and convert `.vue` files to `.js` files :

```js
// compiler.js

import n_fs from 'fs';
import n_url from 'url';
import n_path from 'path';

const __filename = n_url.fileURLToPath(import.meta.url);
const __dirname = n_path.dirname(__filename);

import * as m_compiler from '@vue/compiler-sfc';

let filePath = n_path.resolve(__dirname, './Counter.vue');
let fileContent = n_fs.readFileSync(filePath, 'utf8');
let fileName = n_path.parse(filePath).name;

function transformVueSFC(source, filename){
    
    let {descriptor, errors, } = m_compiler.parse(source, {filename:filename, });
    if(errors.length !== 0){ throw new Error(errors.toString()) };
    let id = Math.random().toString(36).slice(2, 12);
    
    let hasScoped = descriptor.styles.some(function(e){ return e.scoped });
    let scopeId = hasScoped ? `data-v-${id}` : undefined;
    let templateOptions = {
        sourceMap : false,
        filename : descriptor.filename + '.vue',
        id : id,
        scoped : hasScoped,
        slotted : descriptor.slotted,
        source : descriptor.template.content,
        compilerOptions : {
            scopeId : hasScoped ? scopeId : undefined,
            mode : 'module',
        },
    };
    
    let script = m_compiler.compileScript(descriptor, {id, templateOptions, });
    let template = m_compiler.compileTemplate({...templateOptions, });
    
    let renderString = '';
    let startString = script.content.includes(
    'const __default__ = {') ? 'const __default__ = {' : 'export default {';
    
    renderString = template.code.match(/export function render\(_ctx, _cache\) {([\s\S]+)/)[0];
    renderString = renderString.replace('export function render(_ctx, _cache)', 'render(_ctx, _cache)');
    template.code = template.code.replace(/export function render\(_ctx, _cache\) {([\s\S]+)/, '');
    script.content = script.content.replace(startString, function(){
        return (
            startString + "\n"+ 
            renderString +",\n" + 
            "__scopeId : '" + scopeId + "',\n"
            + "__file : '" + fileName + "',\n"
        );
    });
    
    let insertStyles = '';
    if(descriptor.styles){
        let styled = descriptor.styles.map(function(style){
            return m_compiler.compileStyle({id, source:style.content, scoped:style.scoped, preprocessLang:style.lang, });
        });
        if(styled.length){
            let cssCode = styled.map(function(s){ return `${s.code}` }).join('\n');
            insertStyles = (
                "(function(){\n" + 
                    "let styleTag = document.createElement('style');\n" + 
                    "styleTag.setAttribute('data-v-"+ filename +"', '');\n" + 
                    "styleTag.innerHTML = `"+ cssCode +"`;\n" + 
                    "document.head.appendChild(styleTag);\n" + 
                '})();'
            );
        };
    };
    
    let jsFile01 = __dirname + '/'+ fileName + '.js';
    let jsFile01Content = (insertStyles +'\n\n\n\n'+ template.code +'\n\n\n\n'+ script.content);
    jsFile01Content = jsFile01Content.replace(/\n{4,}/g, '\n\n\n\n').trim();
    n_fs.writeFile(jsFile01, jsFile01Content, {flag:'w', }, function(error){
        if(error){ return console.error(error) };
        console.log('✔ : '+ jsFile01);
    });
    
};

transformVueSFC(fileContent, fileName);
```

The following is my `Counter.vue` file, which is in the same directory as the `compiler.vue` file. If it is written in the traditional way, the compilation result can run smoothly, and the `counter.js` file can be executed in the browser , but if it is `<script setup>`, the browser will report an error :

```html
<!-- Counter.vue -->
<template>
    <button type="button" @click="count++">{{ count }}</button>
</template>
<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue';
const count = ref(0);
</script>
```

Here is the compiled result from `Counter.js` :

```js
// Counterjs
import { toDisplayString as _toDisplayString, openBlock as _openBlock, createElementBlock as _createElementBlock } from "vue"
import { ref } from 'vue';

export default {
render(_ctx, _cache) {
  return (_openBlock(), _createElementBlock("button", {
    type: "button",
    onClick: _cache[0] || (_cache[0] = $event => (_ctx.count++))
  }, _toDisplayString(_ctx.count), 1 /* TEXT */))
},
__scopeId : 'undefined',
__file : 'Counter',

  setup(__props, { expose: __expose }) {
  __expose();

const count = ref(0);

const __returned__ = { count, ref }
Object.defineProperty(__returned__, '__isScriptSetup', { enumerable: false, value: true })
return __returned__
}

}
```

This is the compiled `Counter.js` file that I am using in html, DevTool will report an error, showing `vue.esm-browser.js:1513 [Vue warn]: Property "count" was accessed during render but is not defined on instance.` and `vue.esm-browser.js:1513 [Vue warn]: Cannot mutate <script setup> binding "count" from Options API.` :

```html
<!-- html use Counter.js -->
<script async src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/es-module-shims@1.6.3/dist/es-module-shims.min.js"></script>
<script type="importmap">{ "imports":{ "vue":"https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@3.3.4/dist/vue.esm-browser.js" } }</script>

<div id="app01">
    <Counter></Counter>
</div>
<script type="module">
import * as Vue from 'vue';
import Counter from './Counter.js';

let vc01 = Vue.createApp({
    components : {
        'Counter' : Counter,
    },
});
let vi01 = vc01.mount('#app01');
</script>
```

I've been struggling with this compilation problem for a long time, trying to figure it out myself, but failing miserably, I really hope someone can help me, thanks.

---

Later, I referred to Vue's official demo, and found that under the same file content, the compiled result is very similar to mine, except that its `render` function has more `$props, $setup, $data, $options` These four parameters, and it does not use `_ctx.count`, but uses `$setup.count`, the code can run after I modify it, the modified `Counter.js` is below, but I don't know why the compilation has these two different results.

```js
// Counter.js
import { toDisplayString as _toDisplayString, openBlock as _openBlock, createElementBlock as _createElementBlock } from "vue"

import { ref } from 'vue';

export default {
render(_ctx, _cache, $props, $setup, $data, $options) {
  return (_openBlock(), _createElementBlock("button", {
    type: "button",
    onClick: _cache[0] || (_cache[0] = $event => ($setup.count++))
  }, _toDisplayString($setup.count), 1 /* TEXT */))
},
__scopeId : 'undefined',
__file : 'Counter',

  setup(__props, { expose: __expose }) {
  __expose();

const count = ref(0);

const __returned__ = { count, ref }
Object.defineProperty(__returned__, '__isScriptSetup', { enumerable: false, value: true })
return __returned__
}

}
```

Comment: So basically you are trying to compile your component into a JavaScript file. Then use Vue from a CDN to mount your JavaScript component to your app? That's strange use of Vue

Comment: I try to compile the `.vue` file into a `.js` file in NodeJS, and then use it in the traditional way, because my project requires SSR, although projects such as Vite or Nuxt can help me complete the compilation quickly, but they do I don't need some redundant things, because I have my own server framework, I just need component files that can run in the browser, so my development method is not complicated, and it can even be said to be a return to tradition, It's just that I haven't been able to find a third-party module that only helps us compile, so I can only try to write it myself. 

Comment: Perhaps you can compile your Vue components as WebComponents ? There are some examples in the manual.